# What other libraries are required to link to under Windows for a Kotlin static library?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

Starting some Multi-platform kotlin, I have the Android working fine and I can also compile a static Windows library from the same source. This is *nice* :-)

However when linking to that static library I am getting missing symbol errors, such as `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol pthread_once referenced in function _ZN5konan5abortEv`.

Now this specific method, I know, is from pthread, so if I download and add that static library I can fix that error.

There are however a few other missing symbols (such as `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _ZNSt15__exception_ptr13exception_ptrC1ERKS0_ referenced in function _ZL21KonanTerminateHandlerv`) and I can't seem to find out what libraries they are from. Also I cannot find any list of dependencies in the docs.

Does anyone know what libraries I need for linking to a library produced by Kotlin Native on Windows?

Comment: To try and help I am putting together a set of bare projects to show the native builds and the error in Windows. I have yet to add the iOS stuff as I am setting up required mac hardware to do so :-( https://github.com/deive-k-multi-test